# No solution to the well known idMappedPortTCP issue?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2 along with indy 10.5.8.0

i'm experiencing the exact same issue described in this post over 6 years ago!

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/1/213924.html

I've got a simple form with just a idMappedPortTCP component set active.
It works for a few seconds forwarding input/output as expected, than suddenly freezes.
The component stops responding while everything else in the application still works

The pity is the same exact project works like a champ with indy9! but i can't use indy9 i have to stick with indy10 :(

I just can't believe nobody provided either a solution or a workaround for this well known issue yet. There MUST be a solution!

Comment: It's open source. Please feel free to develop a solution and submit it yourself, if the pace of bug fixes isn't to your liking. I'm sure the Indy team would appreciate your help.

Comment: Network components are difficult to use and understand because networks are difficult to use and understand. But it sounds like Remy has said that if you simply enable timeouts (set them to 60 seconds) then the so called "lockup" will then become only a timeout, and not so scary anymore, is it?

Comment: this doesn't really explain why it used to work with indy9.If something works in an earlier version of the compo and than stops working in the next release then there is something wrong.I appreciate Remy's work and efforts of the whole indy staff,but the indy10 version of idMappedPortTCP doesn't work this is a matter of fact.Now we can argue about whether or not the select() has a glitch but it used to work with indy9 now it doesn't and nobody cares.Period.I'll try to figure out a solution myself if ever i'll get it working i'll be happy to share and see the component back to life. thank you

Answer (score 9):

Nothing was done about it back then because there was nothing to do about it.  As I explained in that discussion 6 years ago, the root problem was caused by a frozen API function on Microsoft's part under old OS versions under certain conditions.  That was not an Indy problem back then, it is not an Indy problem today.  Today, the only way `select()` hangs anymore is if it is waiting for a state change on the socket that never occurs.  Since Indy uses infinite timeouts by default, that would look like a hang in Indy when it is really a networking issue instead.  In other words, Indy is waiting for inbound data that never arrives.  You can use a packet sniffer to verify that.

Comment: +1 for awesome answer, and thanks Remy for all your time and help here on SO.